# Sharepoint Timer Job and WSP files

Tags: timer-jobs, solution

I have deployed a couple timer jobs as WSP files for a developer in our test and production environment. I have Uninstalled all of them and removed them form our environments. They no longer show up as features. I have restarted the timer service on all app and front end servers. One of the features of these timer jobs were to send out emails. The emails are still going out which tells me the timer jobs are still running. Please help I need to get rid of these jobs totally.

Comment: What is the version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

Timer job might still be functional if there is no code to delete the timer job, when deactivating the feature.

You can verify the timer jobs using PowerShell or using central admin web site. Below are useful PowerShell commands

```
#Display All timer Jobs:
#-----------------------
Get-SPTimerJob

#Delete a specific timer job
#----------------------------
$timerJob = Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.name -eq "TimerJobName" }
$timerJob.Delete()
```

Also You can disable timer jobs using central admin web site.